# Change form fields based on dropdown values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, drop-down-menu

I have an HTML for in which I have dropdown at the beginning, How do I change the form fields base on selection of dropdown value?
Here is the code.

Like if I select General Inquiry it should display first 2 form fields and the form fields in general div 
If I select Credit Inquiry it should display first 2 form fields and the form fields in credit div 
if I select payment Inquiry it should display first 2 form fields and the form fields in payment div

```html
 <form action="">
        <select name="cases" id="cases">
            <option value="general">General Inquiry</option>
            <option value="credit">Credit Inquiry</option>
            <option value="payment">Payment Issue</option>
        </select><br>
        <label for="email">Email Address <span>*</span></label>
        <input type="text">
        <label for="full name">Full Name <span>*</span></label>
        <input type="text">
        
        
        <div class="general" id="general">
            <label for="documents">Wish to submit any requested documents?</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio">Yes
            <input type="radio" name="radio">No <br><br>
            <label for="select">How did you find out about us?<span>*</span></label><br>
            <select name="case" id="case-type">
                <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
                <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
                <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
            </select><br>
        </div>
        
        <div class="credit" id="credit">
            <label for="Date of Inquiry">Date of Inquiry<span>*</span></label>
            <input type="date">
            <label for="Agency">Agency 3 <span>*</span></label>
            <input type="text">         
        </div>
        
        <div class="payment" id="payment">
            <label for="Service Phone Number">Service Phone Number<span>*</span></label>
            <input type="text">
            <label for="select">Topic<span>*</span></label><br>
            <select name="case" id="case-type">
                <option value="topic1">Topic 1</option>
                <option value="topic2">Topic 2</option>
                <option value="topic3">Topic 3</option>
            </select><br><br>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: You need to write javascript function which will decide what fileds to hide and what to show. on change of dropdown

Comment: Yes I need that Javascript which will decide that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote for case "general"..U can follow this for other cases

```
  $("#cases").change(function () {
            var case = $( "#cases option:selected" ).val();
            if(case=="general")
            {
              //show 2 form fields here and show div
               $("#general").show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: @Muthu, this is not really a great way of doing it, reason being if more items gets added to the list you will need to update the change method

Answer (score 5):

Late to the party here, but here is another way

```
    // hide all the divs
    $('div').hide()

    // Show and hide selected div
    $('#cases').change(function () {
        var value = this.value;

        $('div').hide()
        $('#' + this.value).show();
    });
```

Also created a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5f3p2gzo/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Just hide all divs an show the corresponding one on select change if this is what you mean

```
$('div').hide()
$('#cases').change(function(){
    var v=this.value;
    $('div').hide().filter(function(){return this.id==v}).show()
});
```